# Place to put a Jquery UI dialog, in a spring mvc project (with JSP)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsp, spring-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a Spring mvc project in eclipse. In most cases, for the web pages, i have a composition of various jsp, from a main layout jsp to others jsp files.

I try to put a dialog of jquery UI, but i have various problems.

First, i don't know where is the best place to put the div of the dialog UI. I expect that, the dialog is displayed in upper part of the page, centered, but with so many jsp and div, i get confused.

Second, when show  the dialog, this no have correct style or take style of others div. I know that with Theme roller, is possible to customize the styles, but i don't know where is the best place to put the css file, and how and where include it.

¿How is possible to get darker the page, when is shown the jquery ui dialog? And How to block the other elements on the page? (I try with modal:true, but not works, and i some page the dialog is shown behind others elements)

Sorry for the long question, but i really get confused.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for some sort of [Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can just make the `div` a direct child of the `body` element.
2. Once you use the Themeroller to configure your styles, you will be able to download a bundle of files including the CSS file that the Themeroller generated based on your choices. You should put that CSS file in the `head` of your jsp page, something like:
   `<link href="/yoursite/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
3. The `modal` option is the correct way to achive that as described here: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal